# Nagios plugin check_logfiles users and implementers usage on windows

Tags: windows, plugins, nagios

I'm looking for anyone that is using the Nagios Plugin check_logfiles for Windows.

I have this plugin working under Linux OS.  I am really struggling getting it built and working under Windows OS.

so many things, but I can't get a good plugin built for Windows. I must be doing something wrong, as I see others are successful on this.  the other thing is it is in Perl, I'm now just learning Perl due to this, so, I'm not so up on the programming language of this plugin, which hurts a bit.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\plugins\check_logfiles-3.12\plugins-scripts>check_logfiles -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\contrib\chec
k_logfiles.cfg"
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Nagios::CheckLogfiles" at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\plugins\check_logfiles-3.12\plugins-sc
ripts\check_logfiles.pl line 360.
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

well, sometimes you just have to sit back and laugh at yourself sometimes.

this problem was / is due to the Perl Windows build process and I didn't have internet to CPAN install modules.

I set the env http_proxy= and https_proxy= and I can build successfully.

sorry I panicked. thanks everyone.